# Pyramid's Chameleon renderer template can't be found using relative path

Tags: pyramid, chameleon

I'm new to pyramid. When trying to use chameleon as the templating engine, it fails to find the template when specified with a relative path - It is looking for it at `env35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyramid/` where env35 is the virtual environment I created. It will work however if the full path is specified. It will also work using a relative path using jinja2 as the templating engine.
Why can I not use a chameleon template using relative path?

From the manual

> add_view(...., renderer,...)
>
> This is either a single string term (e.g. json) or a string implying a path or asset specification (e.g. templates/views.pt)
>   naming a renderer implementation. If the renderer value does not
>   contain a dot ., the specified string will be used to look up a
>   renderer implementation, and that renderer implementation will be used
>   to construct a response from the view return value. If the renderer
>   value contains a dot (.), the specified term will be treated as a
>   path, and the filename extension of the last element in the path will
>   be used to look up the renderer implementation, which will be passed
>   the full path. The renderer implementation will be used to construct a
>   response from the view return value.
>
> Note that if the view itself returns a response (see View Callable Responses), the specified renderer implementation is never called.
>
> When the renderer is a path, although a path is usually just a simple relative pathname (e.g. templates/foo.pt, implying that a
>   template named "foo.pt" is in the "templates" directory relative to
>   the directory of the current package of the Configurator), a path can
>   be absolute, starting with a slash on UNIX or a drive letter prefix on
>   Windows. The path can alternately be a asset specification in the form
>   some.dotted.package_name:relative/path, making it possible to address
>   template assets which live in a separate package.
>
> The renderer attribute is optional. If it is not defined, the "null" renderer is assumed (no rendering is performed and the value is
>   passed back to the upstream Pyramid machinery unmodified).

Here are the steps I undertook to set up my environment...

```
export VENV=~/Documents/app_projects/pyramid_tutorial/env35
python3 -m venv $VENV
source $VENV/bin/activate  #activate the virtual environment
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install pyramid 
pip install wheel
pip install pyramid_chameleon
pip install pyramid_jinja2
```

My file structure:

```
pyramid_tutorial
    env35
        bin
        ...
    templates
        hello.jinja2
        hello.pt
    test_app.py
```

test_app.py:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid.view import view_config

def hello(request):
    return dict(name='Bugs Bunny')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')

    #This does not work... http://localhost:6543/chameleon
    config.add_route('hello_world_1', '/chameleon')
    config.add_view(hello, route_name='hello_world_1', renderer='templates/hello.pt')
    # ValueError: Missing template asset: templates/hello.pt (/home/david/Documents/app_projects/pyramid_tutorial/env35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyramid/templates/hello.pt)

    #This works... http://localhost:6543/chameleon2
    config.add_route('hello_world_2', '/chameleon2')
    config.add_view(hello, route_name='hello_world_2', renderer='/home/david/Documents/app_projects/pyramid_tutorial/templates/hello.pt')

    #This works... http://localhost:6543/jinja
    config.add_route('hello_world_3', '/jinja')
    config.add_view(hello, route_name='hello_world_3', renderer='templates/hello.jinja2')

    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 6543, app)
    print ('Serving at http://127.0.0.1:6543')
    server.serve_forever()
```

hello.pt:

```
<p>Hello <strong>${name}</strong>! (Chameleon renderer)</p>
```

hello.jinja2:

```
<p>Hello <strong>{{name}}</strong>! (jinja2 renderer)</p>
```

Comment: FYI, we have a [cookiecutter](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/project.html) that facilitates the process and can provide a working example to compare against. We also don't recommend the use of `activate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you specify `renderer=__name__ + ':templates/hello.pt'`. The resolution logic doesn't work in this case because the file is not being executed as a python package and thus some weird stuff can occur. `pyramid_chameleon` could likely be updated with better support here but by far the common case for real apps is to write your code as a package which will work as expected.

It might also work if you tweak things slighty run your script as a module via `python -m test_app`.